# Create a Horizontal Border In Html Css

Tags: html, css

I need to Write a Text In between a Horizontal line on both sides left and right Here is the image that I need.

[this is what I have to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzdAS.png)

And here is my code of what I have done until

**Html**

```
<section class="explore">
    <div class="heading-tertiory u-center-text">
        <h1>LATEST ITEMS</h1>
        <a class="star_design" href="">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1-of-3">

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Please help me to create a horizontal line between Texts.

Thank You

Comment: Create pseudo elements are give them `border-bottom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this with `:before` and `:after` on the `.star_design` and do something like this:

```css
.heading-tertiory {
  text-align: center;
}

a.star_design {
  color: lightgray;
  /* normalize line height for vertcal centering */
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.star_design:before,
a.star_design:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  /* centers vertically */
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* width half of container minus half of the width of the stars */
  width: calc(50% - 40px);
  height: 1px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

a.star_design:before{
  left: 0;
}

a.star_design:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="explore">
  <div class="heading-tertiory u-center-text">
    <h1>LATEST ITEMS</h1>
    <a class="star_design" href="">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; </a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-of-3">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Pseudo CSS properties. You can use a::before and a::after and add width to them so that it spreads out to the edges. I would recommend that you research a bit before you go doing anything on how to use Pseudo elements.